# How to compare two dates based on another column (SQL)?

Tags: sql

I am trying to compare the prelim_inbound ship date with the inbound ship date.

[See data here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dilnz.png)

The end goal is just that I need to determine the how often the prelim date > inbound date, the prelim date = inbound date, the prelim date < inbound date to determine weather or not the manufacturers are shipping products early, late, or on time. I'm struggling trying to figure out how to do this.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. You might want to look at this article on how to ask a good question including reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Which dbms????  Sample input????  Expected output????  Your query???   
 Help us help you.  Learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I posted a photo of what the data looks like.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DateDiff function:

```
datediff(dd,PrelimShipDate,InboundShipDate) as difference
```

You can use Case When to check if it's positive, negative or zero

```
case when datediff(dd,PrelimShipDate,InboundShipDate)>0 then 1
when datediff(dd,PrelimShipDate,InboundShipDate)=0 then 0
when datediff(dd,PrelimShipDate,InboundShipDate)<0 then -1 end as comparison
```

You could then count the 1s, 0s, & -1s for a how many of each if you like.

Comment: That's the route I was thinking to go but the shipdates and weather or not they are inbound or prelim are in two different columns so that is where I'm confused.

Comment: DateDiff will compare dates from two different columns, it outputs the difference in a new column.

Comment: I know that, what I'm saying all all the dates are in one column. Then there is another column with the shipment type in it. Can you look at the photo in the original post?

Comment: Do you have another column which has some sort of shipment number? You could create a temporary table with only the PrelimShipDates, and another with only the InboundShipDates, then join the two together using that shipment number.

Comment: I do, I'm going to try that. Thank you!